# How to import Swift headers in hybrid Swift/Objective-C CROSS-PLATFORM project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, swift

I am building a cross-platform Mac/iOS quiz app as a demo project.

I created the app as an iOS app, and then added a Mac OS target to the app. I am creating all my shared classes so that they are included in both the iOS and Mac OS targets.

For the Mac side of things, I want to use Cocoa bindings to connect my UI elements to data structures in the app.

To do that, I need to define the data container class(es) that I connect with Cocoa bindings as NSObjects. I've found that Swift objects that inherit from NSObject don't broadcast KVC notifications correctly, so I am creating my data object as native a Objective-C object rather than Swift NSObjects.

However, I seem to have reached a catch-22.

When you want your Objective-C classes to have access to your Swift classes, you're supposed to add an import of the form `#import "<target>-Swift.h"` to the file that needs access to the Swift classes.

Hmm...

My data classes are cross-platform. I want them to be visible to both the iOS and Mac OS targets. Similarly, my data **Container** class, which is written in Objective-C, also needs to be visible to both the Mac OS and iOS targets.

There's the gotcha. I can't use a `#import <ios-target>-Swift.h"` **or** a `#import <mac-target>-Swift.h"` in my Objective-C file, since that the Swift-to-Objective-C bridging header is only defined for one target.

How do I create an Objective-C file that is shared across multiple targets and has access to my cross-platform Swift classes? It's looking like I'll have to create separate Mac and iOS versions of my Objective-C.

P.S. I'm currently using the Xcode 6.3 beta, which includes Swift 1.2.